# How can i show scroll on hover in tippy js?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, tippyjs

I am using tippy.js https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/ for showing tooltip on hover inside my full calendar.
Now everything is fine but i am showing guest list inside it so there can be 100 or even more guest in which case the on hovering the tippy js element covers whole page.

How can i make it scrollable ? i cant find any such property in official docs .

So is there a way to make it scrollable .